# rails +capybara +selenium can not open an external url

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

In a rails project, i add a feature file and step definition try to use capybara+selenium to load an external url,but it can not work? it has no any browser loading behavior,and from the console, it did not request the external url `'http://baidu.com'` but `'http://localhost:3000'` why, how can check for me,thanks very much!

```
**env.rb**
require 'cucumber/rails' 
require 'capybara/rails' 
require 'capybara/cucumber' 
require 'selenium/client'
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium 
Capybara.default_selector = :css

**setp_definition:**
When /^i visit baidu$/ do
  visit('http://www.baidu.com/')

end

Then /^you should see Baidu$/ do
  page.should have_content('Baidu')
end

****the infor on the console:****
```

[31m      expected there to be text "Baidu" in "Browse the documentation Rails
Guides Rails API Ruby core Ruby standard library Welcome aboard You鈥檙e riding
Ruby on Rails! About your application鈥檚 environment Getting started Here鈥檚 h
ow to get rolling: Use rails generate to create your models and controllers To s
ee all available options, run it without parameters. Set up a default route and
remove public/index.html Routes are set up in config/routes.rb. Create your data
base Run rake db:create to create your database. If you're not using SQLite (the
 default), edit config/database.yml 
with your username and password." **(RSpec::Ex
pectations::ExpectationNotMetError)[0m**.